# Mpaobx enable object borders

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to enable borders for map objects like on this link?
I can't find any information about it
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/optimize-map-label-placement/#label-collision

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on those borders like this:

`map.showCollisionBoxes = true`

It's really just for debugging, though.